# Викторина. Как в json прописать несколько вариантов ответов на вопросы в викторине

Tags: javascript, android, json, android-studio

Имею вот такой пример базы данных вопросов и ответов к викторине :

```
{
    "question": "Рентгенологічно у пацієнта діагностовано перелом плечової кістки в ділянці міжгорбкової борозни. Сухожилок якого м’яза може бути травмований уламками кістки в першу чергу? ",
                "answer": [
        "Двоголового м’яза плеча",  
        "Дельтовидного м’яза  ", 
        "Великого круглого м’яза ",  
        "Найширшого м’яза спини  ", 
        "Великого грудного м’яза "
        ],
    "correct_answer":0,
    "question_category":"1"
    },
    {
    "question": "При обстеженні пацієнта з ножовими ранами правої руки встановлено втрату чутливості шкіри бічної половини тильної поверхні кисті та проксимальних фаланг 1-го, 2-го і частково 3-го пальців. Який нерв пошкоджено?  ",
                "answer": [
        " Променевий ",   
        "Серединний  ", 
        "Ліктьовий  ", 
        "М’язово-шкірний  ", 
        "Бічний шкірний передпліччя"
        ],
    "correct_answer":0,
    "question_category":"1"
    },
    {
    "question": "У постраждалого виявлено рану верхньої частини передньої ділянки плеча. При обстеженні встановлена втрата активного згинання в ліктьовому суглобі і чутливості шкіри передньо-бічної поверхні передпліччя. Порушення якого нерва має місце?  ",
                "answer": [
        "м’язово-шкірного  ", 
        "Променевого  ", 
        "Серединного  ", 
        "Ліктьового  ", 
        "Пахвового"
        ],
    "correct_answer":0,
    "question_category":"1"
    },
```

Как сделать в это коде несколько варианте ответов?

Comment: Нет абсолютно верного варианта. Можете `correct_answer` сделать массивом чисел. Элегантно и просто. Можете прям в вопросе ставить вначале + а далее в коде хранить где-то правильный ответ, а + вырезать. Можете вообще хранить правильные и неправильные ответы раздельно а потом кодом смешивать.

Comment: Так а в чём проблема, собственно? У Вас же вроде есть варианты ответов - в массиве `answer`, только он некорректно оформлен (нужно каждый вариант заключить в кавычки и добавить запятые между ними) и в `correct_answer`  указать индекс правильного (вместо `0`)

Comment: @woesss Проблема в том что я хочу сделать несколько правильных вариантов ответов а не один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct_answer задать в виде массива

Comment: correct_answer [ 0, 1, 2, 3],   так вы хотели сказать?

Comment: или так "correct_answer" [ "0", "1", "2", "3"],

Comment: @VladBulan, `"correct_answer" : [ 2, 5, 8]` - в скобках индексы только правильных ответов

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Или `"correct_answer" : [ true, false, true, ...]` - по количеству ответов

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать объект вместо массива:

```
let some = {
    "question": "У постраждалого виявлено рану верхньої частини передньої ділянки плеча. При обстеженні встановлена втрата активного згинання в ліктьовому суглобі і чутливості шкіри передньо-бічної поверхні передпліччя. Порушення якого нерва має місце?",
    "answers": {
        "м’язово-шкірного ": true ,
        "Променевого": false,
        "Серединного": false,  
        "Ліктьового": true,
        "Пахвового": false,

    },                  
    "question_category":"1"
};
```

Но тогда варианты ответов будут выдаваться в случайном порядке.

Comment: Варианты ответов будут выдаваться в случайном порядке и правильные могут стать неправильными и на оборот.

Comment: То есть по вашему коду ответы выдаются случайно и 0 и 3 будут всегда правильными а все остальные нет?

Comment: @VladBulan, связь `"Ліктьового"` и `true` не теряется ни в коем случае, не гарантируется только порядок ответов - то есть теоретически (но не обязательно) `"Ліктьового": true` может оказаться не четвёртым в списке. Хотя я ни разу не замечал, чтобы при парсинге ключи перемешивались.